# Customising the output of items using django-autocomplete-light v3

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-autocomplete-light

In earlier versions of django-autocomplete-light you could use a template to render each returned entry, which included the ability to insert custom HTML

I can't figure out how to do that using the regular API, so I'm trying to add it in.

So far I have a class like this which uses `mark_safe` and the HTML is being passed through:

```
class TemplateRenderSelect2QuerySetView(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_result_label(self, result):
        """Return the label of a result."""
        template = get_template("autocomplete_light/item.html")

        context = Context({"item": result})
        return mark_safe(template.render(context))
```

And the template `autocomplete_light/item.html` is:

```
<b>{{ item.name }}</b>
```

But thats being rendered as:

[image]

But the JSON is correct with the right tags:

```
{"pagination": {"more": false}, "results": [{"text": "<b>Victoria</b>", "id": 11}]}
```

How can I get django-admin to render the HTML properly?

---

edit: I found some [extra documentation](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html?highlight=data-html#displaying-results-using-custom-html) on custom HTML and tried setting `attrs={'data-html': 'true'}` against the widget, but its still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always the answer is subclassing, in this case the tip is to override `get_result_title`:

```
class CustomisableAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    template_name = "autocomplete_light/item.html"

    def get_result_title(self, result):
        """Return the label of a result."""

        template = get_template(self.template_name)
        context = Context({"result": result})
        return template.render(context)
```

If you want to have a title that isn't cluttered with tags, you can override `get_results` and return more data:

```
class CustomisableAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    template_name = "autocomplete_light/item.html"
    def get_result_title(self, result):
        """Return the title of a result."""
        return six.text_type(result)

    def get_result_text(self, result):
        """Return the label of a result."""

        template = get_template(self.template_name)
        context = Context({"result": result})
        return template.render(context)

    def get_results(self, context):
        """Return data for the 'results' key of the response."""
        return [
            {
                'id': self.get_result_value(result),
                'title': self.get_result_title(result),
                'text': self.get_result_text(result),
            } for result in context['object_list']
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**'data-html': True** in the [documentation](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html?highlight=data-html#displaying-results-using-custom-html) works now.

```
    study = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Study.objects.all(),
                                      widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
                                        url='my_studies-autocomplete',
                                        attrs={
                                            'data-placeholder': 'Please select...',
                                            'data-theme': 'bootstrap4',
                                            'data-html': True
                                        })
                                    )
```