# django-autocomplete-light v3 Customising the output of items and conserve it in the form

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

Following this ([Customising the output of items using django-autocomplete-light v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733177/customising-the-output-of-items-using-django-autocomplete-light-v3)), I customise the list of choices.

My code :

```
class WordAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
 ...
 def get_result_label(self, obj):
     template = get_template("autocomplete_light/item.html")
     context = Context({"item": obj})
     return mark_safe(template.render(context))
```

The Form :

```
class SentenceAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta :
     widgets = {
              'word':autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple('WordAutocomplete',
                                                       attrs={'data-html': 'true'}),
               }
```

The Template autocomplete/item.html :

```
<a href="url">{{ item }}</a>
```

As you can see, there are links, one for each item.

And the links are active until I save :

[links are active in the list and in the select box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFdBA.png)

[After saving, the links are no longer there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MqoE.png)

What can I do to maintain the links in the select box ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is straight forward.

First, take a look into this article about select2 itself: [Can I change how the placeholder looks?](https://select2.github.io/options.html#can-i-change-how-the-placeholder-looks)

Okay, so we need to redefine templateResult function or find out how it works at least.

Now go to dal docs: [Overriding javascript code](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#overriding-javascript-code)

Looks like templateResult defined somewhere in autocomplete.init.js. And yes it is over there: [django-autocomplete-light/src/dal_select2/static/autocomplete_light/select2.js:47](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/src/dal_select2/static/autocomplete_light/select2.js#L47)

And the function itself: [django-autocomplete-light/src/dal_select2/static/autocomplete_light/select2.js:7](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/src/dal_select2/static/autocomplete_light/select2.js#L7)

By the way there are `data-html` stuff that you mentioned in your code.

You can debug js code, console.log() it and find out that this function applies on all results. Fetched dynamically while autocomplete is working and also received statically with page html. Which is good, so all you actually need to do is to render select options in the same way as you render autocomplete items. More than that, according to you code, you don't even have to redefine get_result_label() function.

```
class Obj(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        template = get_template("autocomplete_light/item.html")
        context = Context({"item": self.name}) # self.name or whatever
        return template.render(context)
        # or just:
        # return '<a href="url">%s</a>' % self.name

class WordAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    ...
    # Do not redefine get_result_label()
    # def get_result_label(self, obj):
    #     template = get_template("autocomplete_light/item.html")
    #     context = Context({"item": obj})
    #     return mark_safe(template.render(context))

class SentenceAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta :
        widgets = {
            'word': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(
                'WordAutocomplete',
                attrs={'data-html': 'true'}),
        }
```

Comment: With this code, it works :
           
    class Obj(models.Model):
        ...
        def __str__(self):
            return '<a href="url">%s</a>' % self.name
           
But it does not work with : 
           
    class Obj(models.Model):
        ...
        def __unicode__(self):
            return '<a href="url">%s</a>' % self.name           
           
Anyway you helped me to do it !